# Extent transparent image with color using ImageMagick

Tags: image, background, resize, imagemagick

I would like to extent an image with a (for example) a red border using this command line:

```
convert input.png -gravity center -background red -extent 1000x1000 output.png
```

This works as long as the input.png does not contain any transparent regions.

If it does these will also be replaced by the background color. I've read in the documentation that this is expected behaviour and the solution would be to remove the background color (which I cannot as I would like to have a colored border) or to use an alpha compositor (which I am not able to figure out the correct one).

How can I extend an image using an color but applying the color only to the extended area and not the original image itself?

**Edit:**
According to the description of the compose parameter i think it should work with

```
-compose src-in
```

but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can get you what you want but I suspect the method is a little clumsy, so I will keep thinking and alert our resident expert @KurtPfeifle, who knows everything ImageMagick....

In the meantime, my idea would be to create your red, extended background, *punch a transparent hole in it the size of your original image* then overlay your original image, like this:

```
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:red                                                      \
        -size 800x800   xc:none -alpha set -gravity center -compose copy -composite \
        image.png -composite result.png
```

The first line creates the red background, the second line punches a transparent hole the size of my original image (800x800), and the third copies the original image onto the transparent hole.

If you are using `bash`, you can get the geometry from the original image like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
geom=$(convert image.png -format "%wx%h" info:)
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:red                                                  \
        -size $geom xc:none -alpha set -gravity center -compose copy -composite \
        image.png -composite result.png
```

So, if I start with this

[image]

I end up with this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try drawing a color at the first pixel of the extented image.

```
convert input.png -gravity center \
             -extent 1000x1000 \
             -fill red \
             -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' \
             output.png
```

[image: draw color]

#### Edit

Another approach is to "bleed" a border past the expected extent range. This is a common technique in printing, and works knowing the extra border would be ignored.

```
convert input.png \
             -mattecolor red \
             -frame 1000x1000+0+0 \
             -gravity Center \
             -extent 1000x1000 \
             output.png
```

[image: frame]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Transparent backround of image is also red afterwards.

Comment: This probably would only work if the source image has a non-transparent border.